# Getting 404 for jwt token request in release mode

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin, jwt, katana

I am new to ASP.NET or C# programming. In my new assignment, I am working on adding authentication middleware, checking JWT token for validation, etc.
I followed this URL to add an authentication middleware to my ASP.net application - http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2015/01/15/using-json-web-tokens-with-katana-and-webapi.aspx

While I have been successful in getting the token generated when accessing the /token url, this has been though been possible when running only in Debug mode. If I change the build configuration to Release, accessing /token url, starts giving me 404 error.

I compared the output that shows up in the Visual Studio 2013 Output view and found extra 2 lines in the debug mode that do not show up in Release mode.
The two lines are -

'MetaAPI.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MetaAPI.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'MetaAPI.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MetaAPI.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

I do not know if these indicate the root of the problem. I added reference to System.Web and System.Web.Extensions to the project, but it did not help.

How to fix this? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely because of `#if DEBUG` condition

```
public class MyOAuthOptions : OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
    public MyOAuthOptions()
    {
        TokenEndpointPath = "/token";
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
        AccessTokenFormat = new MyJwtFormat();
        Provider = new MyOAuthProvider();
        #if DEBUG // HERE
            AllowInsecureHttp = true;
        #endif
    }
}
```

In `Release Mode` the `MyOAuthOptions` expect traffic over `HTTPS`. Just remove the `#if DEBUG` and `#endif` and keep `AllowInsecureHttp = true` if you test your application on local machine or insecure http.

**Bear in mind** though that on production environment the HTTPS is a must and above code should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed the issue,